# Spring MVC MultipartFilter not working, getParts() returns null

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, multipartform-data, servlet-filters

The framework I am using is Spring Framework 4.2.4 And server is using JBOSS/Wildfly version 10.0.
And the front is using JSP.

I want to apply `multipartFilter`.

I tried a lot, but the value becomes `null` when I get to the `Controller`
I checked Debug in Filter, but `getparts()` was null.

But Unless it's `multipart/form-data`, XSS Filter works fine.

I'm using `navercorp.lucy` for my XSS filter.

This is my `web.xml`

```xml
<filter>
        <filter-name>multipartFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MultipartFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>multipartFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>xssEscapeServletFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.navercorp.lucy.security.xss.servletfilter.XssEscapeServletFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>xssEscapeServletFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

And I changed the `MultipartResolver` frequency to

```xml
<beans:bean id="filterMultipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
    <beans:property name="maxUploadSize" value="102400000" />
</beans:bean>
```

I thought it might be an input stream issue, so I created my own wrapper and tried to apply it, but it failed.

I couldn't try `AllowCasualMultipartParsing="true"` because I wasn't using Tomcat.

Q1. Is there a source where I can create a `MultipartFilter` myself?

Q2. How do I use `MultipartFilter` correctly?

Comment: I think XSS filter is not problem if only Xss filter exist it work but add `MultipartFilter`then is not working